# PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 72 bytes)

Tags: phpmyadmin

```
if (function_exists('mb_detect_encoding') && false !== $encoding mb_detect_encoding($params[$index]))
{
  if (self::MAX_STRING_LENGTH < mb_strlen($params[$index], $encoding))
  {
    $params[$index] = mb_substr($params[$index], 0, self::MAX_STRING_LENGTH - 6, $encoding) . ' [...]';
    continue;
  }
} else {
  if (self::MAX_STRING_LENGTH < strlen($params[$index])) 
  {
      $params[$index] = substr($params[$index], 0, self::MAX_STRING_LENGTH - 6) . ' [...]';
      continue;
  }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you made an infinite loop. But I honestly never had this problem.

Comment: this is not enough to know what's using memory.  Infinite loop is possible, or unbounded array growth.  Where's the loop that is `continue`d?

Comment: why is this code snippet included with the question?  with memory exhaustion, one part of the code could have used up almost all memory to have a completely unrelated part of code break somewhere else

Answer (score 1):

Hi modify memory limit on your `php.ini`

`memory_limit = 75M`

```
/*
 * This file is part of the Symfony package.
 *
 * (c) Fabien Potencier <fabien@symfony.com>
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
 * file that was distributed with this source code.
 */

 namespace Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Logger;

use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Stopwatch\Stopwatch;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Logging\SQLLogger;

/**
 * DbalLogger.
 *
 * @author Fabien Potencier <fabien@symfony.com>
 */
class DbalLogger implements SQLLogger
{
const MAX_STRING_LENGTH = 32;
const BINARY_DATA_VALUE = '(binary value)';

protected $logger;
protected $stopwatch;

/**
 * Constructor.
 *
 * @param LoggerInterface $logger    A LoggerInterface instance
 * @param Stopwatch       $stopwatch A Stopwatch instance
 */
public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger = null, Stopwatch $stopwatch = null)
{
    $this->logger = $logger;
    $this->stopwatch = $stopwatch;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function startQuery($sql, array $params = null, array $types = null)
{
    if (null !== $this->stopwatch) {
        $this->stopwatch->start('doctrine', 'doctrine');
    }

    if (is_array($params)) {
        foreach ($params as $index => $param) {
            if (!is_string($params[$index])) {
                continue;
            }

            // non utf-8 strings break json encoding
            if (!preg_match('#[\p{L}\p{N} ]#u', $params[$index])) {
                $params[$index] = self::BINARY_DATA_VALUE;
                continue;
            }

            // detect if the too long string must be shorten
            if (function_exists('mb_detect_encoding') && false !== $encoding = mb_detect_encoding($params[$index])) {
                if (self::MAX_STRING_LENGTH < mb_strlen($params[$index], $encoding)) {
                    $params[$index] = mb_substr($params[$index], 0, self::MAX_STRING_LENGTH - 6, $encoding).' [...]';
                    continue;
                }
            } else {
                if (self::MAX_STRING_LENGTH < strlen($params[$index])) {
                    $params[$index] = substr($params[$index], 0, self::MAX_STRING_LENGTH - 6).' [...]';
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (null !== $this->logger) {
        $this->log($sql, null === $params ? array() : $params);
    }
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function stopQuery()
{
    if (null !== $this->stopwatch) {
        $this->stopwatch->stop('doctrine');
    }
}

/**
 * Logs a message.
 *
 * @param string $message A message to log
 * @param array  $params  The context
 */
protected function log($message, array $params)
{
    $this->logger->debug($message, $params);
}
}
```

Comment: please explain, I don't see why that would help

Answer (score 0):

```
ini_set("memory_limit","72M");
```

Comment: how's that going to help?  memory got exhausted at 256M